# Remove spacing between a <div> and a <p> tags

Tags: html, css

I am writing an HTML Document. I am trying to make no space between a p and a div. There were no error messages included.

I have already tried:

- adding 0px margin, padding to the p element and div element
- making no whitespace between them in the code

Code:

```css
#IO-out {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.pn {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.t {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  font-family: "Roboto Mono", monospace, "wingdings";
}

.t.normal {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
html

<head>
  <title>
    ivyghostkit
  </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="common.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body class="t normal">
  <div id="container">
    <div id="IO-out" class="t normal">
      <!-- p elements with class "pn" are added here using javascript -->
    </div>
    <p id="VoidKeyboard"></p>
  </div>
  <script src="g.core.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

For clarification, the problem is that noticeable space is inbetween `#VoidKeyboard` and all `p` elements in `#IO-out`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Add this in your css file**

```
p{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

And add some text in your  markup..

**Here is the full code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>

#IO-out {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    /** make void keyboard work **/
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
p{
  margin: 0;
  padding: ;
}
.pn {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.t {
    color:  white;
    background-color: black;
    font-family: "Roboto Mono", monospace, "wingdings"; /** ;) **/
}
.t.normal {
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
}
  </style>
</head>

    <body class="t normal">
        <div id="container">
            <div id="IO-out" class="t normal">
                p elements with class "pn" are added here using javascript
            </div>
            <p id="VoidKeyboard">Remove Spacing</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, I just have to wait a minute before marking your solution as correct.

Comment: @ObscuredツDon't mention it, keep it up..